# Micronaut autowired equivalent with no constructor

Tags: micronaut

I'm beginer in micronaut and I'm confused about how to inject dependencies in some cases.

I need to user a service into a json deserializer:

```
public class DecryptSerializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {


private MyService myService ;



@Override
public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
    try {
        return myService.decrypt(p.getValueAsString());
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
}
```

In spring I use to do it like this:

```
@Component
public class DecryptSerializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {
private static MyService myService;

@Autowired
public void setCryptoService(MyService myService){
    DecryptSerializer.myService= myService;
}

@Override
public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
    try {
        return myService.decrypt(p.getValueAsString());
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
}
}
```

Who can I do it in micronaut?

Answer (score 0):

> Micronaut autowired equivalent with no constructor

In Micronaut you can use `@jakarta.inject.Inject` on a property or a setter method.  Instead of this:

```
@Autowired
public void setCryptoService(MyService myService){
    DecryptSerializer.myService= myService;
}
```

You could have this:

```
@Inject
public void setCryptoService(MyService myService){
    // initializing a static property like this is a bad idea,
    // but unrelated to the question.
    DecryptSerializer.myService= myService;
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of examples in the docs and in Micronaut itself.  See the following: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/0f4bba77e6869a126946ebec1f74f1fc0b37640f/http/src/main/java/io/micronaut/http/ssl/ClientSslConfiguration.java#L69-L74, https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/0f4bba77e6869a126946ebec1f74f1fc0b37640f/http/src/main/java/io/micronaut/http/ssl/ClientSslConfiguration.java#L82-L87